# Is there enough information given to solve this related rates problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is the question from a practice exam:

Suppose a pyramid has 4 lateral faces that are all equilateral triangles. Find the rate at which the volume of the pyramid is changing if each side of each triangle increases at a rate of 2 inches per second. Hint: The volume of a square pyramid is given by the formula $V={1\over 3}Bh$, where $B$ is the area of the base of the pyramid and $h$ is the height of the pyramid.

This is the only information I am given. The answer key has just been released, so I know the answer is $16\sqrt{2}in^3/sec$, but I don't know how to get there. And then a friend (who was helping me) thought that maybe there isn't enough information.

Is there enough?

EDIT: I used the answer given by the key and worked out the problem. I believe that the missing information is "Find the rate at which the volume of the pyramid is changing when the side length is 4 inches." When I put $h$ (height) in terms of $s$ (side length), then differentiated implicitly, and plugging in $4$ for $s$ at the end, I found the solution to be ${16\cdot2\over \sqrt{2}}$, which simplifies to $16\sqrt{2}$ by rationalizing the denominator.

Comment: Is this assumed to be a square pyramid?

Comment: Yes, my professor wouldn't have given the volume of a square pyramid if it wasn't meant to be one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not enough information, if you assume that the pyramid is interpreted in the usual way, in the sense of having a square base. Then you can express all the information in terms of the side length. Since the the base is a square, and the height is $\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Here's a reference on this type of solid. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramid

Now you can just use the normal implicit differentiation technique to see that $\frac{dV}{dt} = f(s)\frac{ds}{dt}$ for an appropriate function of $s$. However,  nowhere in the statement of the problem were you told any information at all about the side length, and there doesn't seem to be a way to deduce it. So unless you leave your answer in this form, you can't go forward.

Comment: Yes, I have expressed everything in terms of side length. But I haven't been able to come with an answer. I know that the rate rate at which the sides are increasing--2 inches per second--and I know how to find the volume. From my past experience with related rates problems I've needed information like the time elapsed, or the height at a given moment. Because that's what a derivative is, the instantaneous rate of change.

Comment: Oh I see your concern. For your purpose it wasn't enough to express in terms of $s$. If that's the case, then I don't see it either. In which case I should edit my answer to agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

$l$ is the side's length and $h$ the pyramid's  height.

Using Pythagoras' theorem it's trivial to show that the height respects:

$(l/2)^2 + (l/2)^2 + h^2 = l^2$

solve for $h= \frac{l}{\sqrt{2}}$

$B = l^2$ so $V = \frac{Bh}{3} = \frac{l^3}{3\sqrt{2}} $

$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{l^2}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{dl}{dt}$

So the answer clearly depends on $l$.

This would clearly always be the case.

Just by dimensional analysis V grows as $l^3$ so the rate of change will always grow as $l^2$.

Unless I'm missing something I think this is it.

Comment: That's the same result I got, but based on this being a college assignment and Alfred's answer I worry I must be missing something, yet I can't see anything wrong with the above logic.

Comment: Only thing I could think is that since $\frac{dV}{dt}$ simplifies to $\sqrt{2}l^2$ that perhaps it was somehow assumed to be a triangle of side length 4?

Comment: Volume will always be $Cl^3$ where $C$ is a constant. Rate of change will always depend on $l^2$. If you don't know $l$ you can't compute it numerically. It even makes sense intuitively. My fear is that you might be misinterpreting the question...

Comment: I'm not the asker by the way.

Comment: How would you find $l$? From what I can tell the problem is missing information that dictates what the rate of change of the volume is at that instant. To do that there needs to be another piece of information, like what the volume is, which could be used to find a side length.

Comment: I do not think you can, you'd have to be given some other information, you can find everything in terms of the side length $l$, but without that length merely knowing its rate of change will not allow you to acquire a numerical result for the rate of change of the volume.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but maybe @user252453 has some insight.

Comment: If I interpret the problem correctly. Either $l$ is given directly on indirectly or there's not enough information to answer. I still lean towards misinterpreted question.